# Omnithread unobserved nested thread not released when expected

Tags: multithreading, delphi, rad-studio, omnithreadlibrary

**Background**

My Flagship App seems to leak memory. Well, not really but just during runtime. Investigating this showed the memory 'leak' is resolved when the app closes, but not in between.

I am using a background thread , that iself starts another thread. Both threads (parent and child) are 'Unobserved' which should result in the TOmniTaskControl object to be released and freed when the tread is finished.

**Experimenting code**

```
procedure TfrmMain.MyTestProc(const aTask: IOmniTask);
begin
  sleep(100);
  SGOutputDebugStringFmt('%s.MyTestProc for %s',[ClassName,aTask.Name]);
  sleep(100);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.MyNestedTestProc(const aTask: IOmniTask);
var lTask:IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  sleep(100);
  SGOutputDebugStringFmt('%s.MyTestProc for %s',[ClassName,aTask.Name]);
  lTask:=CreateTask(MyTestProc,'NestedTask');
  lTask.Unobserved.Run;
  sleep(100);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btSimpleThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
var lTask:IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  lTask:=CreateTask(MyTestProc,'SimpleThread');
  lTask.Unobserved.Run;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btNestedThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
var lTask:IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  lTask:=CreateTask(MyNestedTestProc,'NestedThread');
  lTask.Unobserved.Run;
end;
```

When debugging, and setting breakpoint on `TOmniTaskControl.Destroy`, and having a watch `TOmniTaskControl.Name` on  I see the following:

- btSimpleThreadCLick:

  1. TOmniTaskControl for 'SimpleThread' gets to be created
  2. TOmniTaskControl for 'SimpleThread' gets to be destroyed
- btNestedThreadCLick:

  1. TOmniTaskControl for 'NestedThread' is Created
  2. TOmniTaskControl for 'NestedTask' is Created
  3. TOmniTaskControl for 'NestedThread' is Destroyed

**Problem:** TOmniTaskControl for 'NestedTask' is NOT destroyed. Another issue is that the OnTerminate isn't called either.
Then, when closing the app, the `TOmniTaskCOntrol` for 'SimpleThread' is destroyed. (And also, the `OnTherminate` is fired)

**Workaround**

I came up with this solution which seems to do the trick. The thing is however, I do usually NOT run my subthreads from a form where a TOmniEventMonitor is at hand. So I'd have to create a *global* `TOmniEventMonitor` object for this.
But isn't this the whole point of the `UnObserved` method?

```
procedure TfrmMain.MyNestedTestProc(const aTask: IOmniTask);
var lTask:IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  sleep(100);
  SGOutputDebugStringFmt('%s.MyTestProc for %s',[ClassName,aTask.Name]);
  lTask:=CreateTask(MyTestProc,'NestedTask');
  lTask.MonitorWith(OmniEventMonitor).Run; // OmniEventMonitor is a component on my form
  sleep(100);
end;
```

Well, secondary workarounbd... kind-of. It does not allow for my thread to be freed unattended.
if I change the `NestedTestProc` to the code below, then the NestedTaskgets to be destroyed at the expected moment. Unfortunately, this solution is clearly not 'Unobserved'

```
procedure TfrmMain.MyNestedTestProc(const aTask: IOmniTask);
var lTask:IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  sleep(100);
  SGOutputDebugStringFmt('%s.MyTestProc for %s',[ClassName,aTask.Name]);
  lTask:=CreateTask(MyTestProc,'NestedTask');
  try
    lTask.Run;
    lTask.WaitFor(2000);
  finally
    lTask:=nil;
  end;
  sleep(100);
end;
```

**Update 20201029 >>**

An invalid handle (1400) error typically occurs when the master task was completed and its associated Monitor was already destroyed.
So - The 'Master' task thread should not die in case there is an "owned" monitor that is monitoring other threads.

So to check this, I changed the timing (using sleep()) to ensure the child task was completed *before* the master task is completed.
The Invalid handle error is gone now, and the COmniTaskMsg_Terminated message gets to be posted successfully.
But still the ComniTaskMsg_Terminated from the child task is not processed. (I expected the thread of the MasterTask to handle this.)
IMO there are 2 problems:

1. life time management of the Unobserved monitor
2. shutdown management of the Unobserved monitor, which should keep the "owning" thread alive and keep processing messages until all
   monitored threads/tasks are gone.

Also I wonder whether these shutdownmessages hould be handled/processed by the Application main thread (It seems this is the case now) or otherwise through a separate thread that checks all the monitors in `GTaskControlEventMonitorPool` . AIA, pretty complicated stuff :s...

Giving this some thought, monitors that were created by the application main thread (thus `Monitor.ThreadID=MainThreadID`) should be handle their messages in the main thread message loop, and all others probably need to be handled by a separate thread... Its just too confusing! I will see if I write a unit test for this, just to demonstrate what I expect to happen.

**<< Update 20201029**

**The question**

With `OmniThreadLibrary`, How can I use *unobserved* threads inside threads, and avoid the described memory leak?

Comment: The help mentions "This method makes the task being observed by an internal monitor." Looks like that internal monitor is holding onto / keeping it alive longer than you want.

Comment: I thought at first about a non-released interface caused by RSP-29564, but this adjusting my code didn't help. Using the TOmniEventMonitor component on my main form made the problem go away. I also noticed the release call comes from a message handler DsiWIn32. Except for when it is a nested thread using the UnObserved method.

Comment: @Brian - exactly.